# Deleting movieclip and clearing memory AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, memory-management

Another question from me.
For example I've made something like this.

```
    var unit:Array = new Array()
    public function add_unit()        
    {
        unit[unit.length] = new unitclass(parameter)
    }

    public function remove_unit(index)
    {
       for(var i:int = index; i< unit.length; i++)
        {
            unit[i] = unit[i+1]
        }
        unit.pop()
    }
```

Will after using function remove_unit, with specified id the stage will be totaly clear of the array element? If not how do I clear it properly?

Comment: Why aren't you using actionscript's native array methods?

Comment: Also, the short answer to your question is no, the code you've posted above will not remove an object from stage.

Comment: You still didn't answer the whole question. What should I use then?

Comment: I am not trying to answer your question fully. If I was I would have posted an answer rather than a comment. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand your question...

To add an element to an array use `unit.push(new [your_object]());`

To remove an element from an array use `unit.splice([index], 1);`

To add an element to display object(Stage, Sprite, Movieclip etc..) use `[DisplayObject].addChild([element]);`

To remove a element from a display object(Stage, Sprite, Movieclip etc..) use `[DisplayObject].removeChild([element]);`

Removing an element from an array wont remove it from the stage, you must call removeChild with the object you wish to remove from the display list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok. I'm not used to as3, so I don't know many commands yet.
Still can you tell me: if I use these functions above the effect will be achieved? I just want to add unit to array and then remove it from memory.
I'm just noticing that my application is starting to jam and I don't really know why is this happening. Does this action clear the memory properly? I tried using splice and push instead of the method mentioned at the beginning, but this doesn't seem to help.